# How can I elegantly prevent QThread from being destroyed or garbage collected?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
class CustomThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, target, args=()):
        super().__init__()
        self.__target = target
        self.__args = args

    def run(self):
        self.__target(*self.__args)

class MyClass:
    def target(self):
        print("Hello world")
        # Do something
    def func(self):
        thread = CustomThread(self.target)
        thread.start()
```

In this case, the program crashes if I call func() of MyClass, stating that qthread has been destroyed while running. (Because thread is a local variable)
So, I change thread into self.thread, making it be a member variable of MyClass so that it would not be destroyed.

```
class CustomThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, target, args=()):
        super().__init__()
        self.__target = target
        self.__args = args

    def run(self):
        self.__target(*self.__args)

class MyClass:
    def target(self):
        print("Hello world")
        # Do something
    def func(self):
        self.thread = CustomThread(self.target)
        self.thread.start()
```

However, running thread can be potentially garbage collected if I call func() twice or more and program will crash. 
So, I tried to solve this by adding a list and append every thread.

```
class CustomThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, target, args=()):
        super().__init__()
        self.__target = target
        self.__args = args

    def run(self):
        self.__target(*self.__args)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.threads = []
    def target(self):
        print("Hello world")
        # Do something
    def func(self):
        self.thread = CustomThread(self.target)
        self.threads.append(self.thread)
        self.thread.start()
```

This solves the problem, but it looks so inefficient and immature.
Also I have to pop every thread which finishes its job. (Maybe I have to implement it with signal and slot, and of course it looks redundant)

How can I solve this problem more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but with lots of threads list maintenance can get tedious, as threads need to be periodically checked to see if they're complete. Luckily, `QThread` has a `finished` signal, which is called from the Qt loop when the thread is complete. Change your thread list to a dictionary, and connect this signal to a slot to clean it up, using a unique thread id to identify which thread has quit.

```
import time

class CustomThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, target, callback, args=()):
        super().__init__()
        self.callback = callback
        self.__target = target
        self.__args = args
        self.finished.connect(lambda: self.callitback)
    def run(self):
        self.__target(*self.__args)
    def callitback(self):
        self.callback()


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.threads = {}
    def target(self):
        print("Hello world")
        # Do something
    def threadFinished(self, threadId):
        self.threads.pop(threadId, None)
    def func(self):
        threadId = time.time() 
        thread = CustomThread(self.target, lambda tid=threadId: self.threadFinished(tid))
        self.threads[threadId] = thread
        thread.start()
```

Comment: Thanks. finished signal would be convenient